# R as.numeric() changes values (not a factor issue)

Tags: r

The as.numeric() function is arbitrarily changing the values of a number which is in character format. (This is not an issue with calling as.numeric() on a factor.) I am totally stumped. Any thoughts?

```
> "74156618463805445" %>% as.numeric()
[1] 74156618463805440
> "74156618463805446" %>% as.numeric()
[1] 74156618463805440
> "74156618463805449" %>% as.numeric()
[1] 74156618463805456

> sessionInfo()
R version 4.1.0 (2021-05-18)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Mojave 10.14.4

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] dplyr_1.0.7    tidytext_0.3.1 rtweet_0.7.0   twitteR_1.1.9 

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.7        pillar_1.6.1      compiler_4.1.0    tokenizers_0.2.1  tools_4.1.0       bit_4.0.4        
 [7] jsonlite_1.7.2    lifecycle_1.0.0   tibble_3.1.2      lattice_0.20-44   pkgconfig_2.0.3   rlang_0.4.11     
[13] Matrix_1.3-3      rstudioapi_0.13   cli_2.5.0         DBI_1.1.1         curl_4.3.1        janeaustenr_0.1.5
[19] httr_1.4.2        generics_0.1.0    vctrs_0.3.8       askpass_1.1       bit64_4.0.5       grid_4.1.0       
[25] tidyselect_1.1.1  glue_1.4.2        R6_2.5.0          fansi_0.5.0       purrr_0.3.4       magrittr_2.0.1   
[31] SnowballC_0.7.0   ellipsis_0.3.2    assertthat_0.2.1  utf8_1.2.1        stringi_1.6.2     openssl_1.4.4    
[37] crayon_1.4.1      rjson_0.2.20
```

Comment: Your integers are greater than 2^31 which means they can no longer be stored as 32bit but need to be converted to 64bit. There is numerical precision that is lost. See the 64bit package documentation https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bit64/index.html

If these are IDs or keys where you need high fidelity I would leave them as character strings. These numbers are huge. Hopefully you don't have to precisely count grains of sand.

Answer (score 0):

you need the gmp package.

numeric <- as.bigz(character)